# Where is the boot delay for setting up network interfaces configured in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04, networking, timeout

In Ubuntu 14.04 and below, there is a file located in `/etc/init/rc-sysconfig.conf` or `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` that pauses the startup process for up to two minutes if the NICs on the machine are not alive.

Ubuntu 16.04 appears to do away with both of these files, yet there is still a delay if it takes a while to bring the network interfaces up.

Where is this delay configured on 16.04 and up?